# READ TEXT FILE AND CONVERT TO JSON IN JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to reading a txt file that has the following data:

```
number code date        type    name
1       232 2018-09-11  normal  luis
2       44  2018-09-11  normal  lucas
3       42  2018-09-11  normal  jean
4       5   2018-09-11  normal  nil
```

But I need to convert that to json object like this:

```
[
 {  "number": 1,
    "code": 232,
    "date": "2018-09-11",
    "type": "normal",
    "name": "luis"
 },
 {  "number": 2,
    "code": 44,
    "date": "2018-09-11",
    "type": "normal",
    "name": "lucas"
 }
]
```

I was trying something like:

```
var all_data_txt = JSON.parse(read_txt_content);
```

But I don't know what to do,
tahnks in advance

Comment: Your text file in in CSV format. Simply knowing that term should now be more than enough for you to find the solution to parsing that in JS all on your own.

Comment: is in .txt format :(

Comment: No, the _file_ is a txt file, the _data_ is plain text CSV, in the same way that JSON is plain text, and LaTeX is plain text, and Markdown is plain text, etc. etc. Don't look at the file extension, look at the data, and parse based on that.

Comment: can you explain me with a example?

Comment: [This module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-csv-to-json) may help you !

Comment: @Israel you seem to have missed the "you can now find this, yourself" part of my initial comment. Google for "parse CSV file in javascript" and you'll find answers both off-site AND right here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: No, I don't understand someone can help me with code of ssolution